# How does the JavaScript optional chaining(?.) operator works?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-next, optional-chaining

I was looking into the new JS optional chaining[`?.`](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/latest-features-javascript-ecmascript-2020) operator. It helps us from getting errors like this,

```
TypeError: Cannot read property ‘x’ of undefined
```

You can write

```
const obj = {a: 1};
console.log(obj?.b);
```

without an error. It will return `undefined` if there is no property named `b` in the `obj` object. Now, this is working for the first level of (.) operators. But if I try something like this,

```
console.log(obj.b.c.d?.e);
```

This is throwing an error,

```
Uncaught TypeError: obj.c is undefined // In firefox it throws obj.b is undefined.
```

But if I write,

```
console.log(obj.b?.c.d?.e);
```

It is returning undefined again. Shouldn't it be returning `Uncaught TypeError: obj.b.c is undefined`?

Is this some implementation gap or am I missing something here? Thanks in advance.

It is resolved now. @Ifaruki's comment has the proper explanation.

***Update:its called "chaining" operator. it moves from left to right. if it sees ?. it checks the left value if its undefined. if yes it returns undefined and stops moving to the right. that means if b is already undefined it wont check the values on the right side***

Comment: its called "chaining" operator. it moves from left to right. if it sees `?.` it checks the left value if its undefined. if yes it returns undefined and stops moving to the right. that means if `b` is already undefined it wont check the values on the right side

Comment: _"It will return `undefined` if there is no property named `b` in the `obj` object"_. It's more like: "It will return `undefined` if the object `obj` itself is `null` or `undefined`; or if the object `obj` exists but doesn't have the property `b`."

Comment: _"The `?.` operator functions similarly to the `.` chaining operator, except that instead of causing an error if a reference is `null`ish (`null` or `undefined`), the expression short-circuits with a return value of `undefined`."_

Comment: Thanks all. @Ifaruki, your explanation was helpful especially.

Comment: In both your first and second example, the optional chaining operator makes no difference from the regular property accessor. `obj?.b` simply reads `b` (which is `undefined`), since `obj` is not nullish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its called "optional chaining" operator. It moves from left to right. if it sees `?.` it checks the left value if its `undefined` or `null`. if yes, it returns `undefined` and stops moving to the right. that means if `b` is already `undefined` it wont check the values on the right side

Answer (score 1):

In the example below, obj has only one key a.

```
const obj = {a: 1};
console.log(obj?.b);
```

In the above code snippet, there is no property b in object because of which it is printing **undefined**.

```
console.log(obj.b.c.d?.e);
console.log(obj.b?.c.d?.e);
```

Even in the code above, the same thing is happening where the object is not having key **b** hence it is printing undefined. So if you want to see that obj.b.c is undefined then the object should look the one below:

```
obj: {
    b: '123'
}
```